# Say How to use FormArray for dynamic form in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I'm using form Array for Dynamic form with add and delete functionality in that. I'm having two drop down in each array.my question is how i can dynamically change select option of second drop down corresponding to first drop down which will not affect other list in array.

HTML:-

```
<form [formGroup]="invoiceForm">
    <div formArrayName="itemRows">
        <div *ngFor="let itemrow of invoiceForm.controls.itemRows.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
            <h4>Invoice Row #{{ i + 1 }}</h4>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div for="accessCategory" class="dropdown bootstrap-select accessCategoryListings">
                            <div class="select">
                                <select class="form-control" formControlName="userGroup">
                                    <option [ngValue]="opt" *ngFor="let opt of option">{{opt}}</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div for="accessCategory" class="dropdown bootstrap-select accessCategoryListings">
                            <div class="select">
                                <select class="form-control" formControlName="userProfile">
                                    <option [ngValue]="opt" *ngFor="let opt of getDynamicOptions(i)">{{opt}}</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input formControlName="patterns" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteRow(i)"><i class="fa fa-trash"
                                aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <!-- <button *ngIf="invoiceForm.controls.itemRows.controls.length > 1"  >Delete Button</button> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

This is my html Page where im having two drop down in which formControlName="userProfile"  will dynamically changd based on formControlName="userGroup" for each iteration.

```
Component:-

  ngOnInit() {
    this.invoiceForm = this._fb.group({
      itemRows: this._fb.array([this.initItemRows()])
    });
  }

  get formArr() {
    return this.invoiceForm.get('itemRows') as FormArray;
  }

  initItemRows() {
    return this._fb.group({
      userGroup: [''],
      userProfile: [''],
      patterns: ['']
    });
  }


  getDynamicOptions(data: any){
    var selectedData=this.invoiceForm.get('itemsRows')[data];
    this.service.get('/getOption/control'+selectedData).subscribe(resp=>{ 
     return  resp 
   })

  }
```

This is my component in which i have a method called getDynamicOptions
where i used to get formArray index and get selected value form First dropdown and make an Api call to get second dropdown Value. but its not actually not happend what im expecting

I expected to get corresponding drop down value based on another dropdown DropDown in same Array

```
example:

{
  "itemRows": [
    {
      "userGroup": "group1 first drop down",
      "userProfile": "group1 related drop down",
      "patterns": ""
    },
    {
      "userGroup": "group2 first drop down",
      "userProfile": "group2 related drop down",
      "patterns": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide stackblitz example with your problem??

Comment: Might be this example can help you http://keepnote.cc/code/dynamic-form-generate-from-json-angular-2-reactive-form